# Parentheses in django if statement

Tags: python, django, templates, django-templates, django-views

How can I do this  cleanly in a Django template?  Basically if A, or (B and C) , I want to show some HTML.

I basically have this:

{% if user.is_admin or something.enable_thing and user.can_do_the_thing %}

Now, thats a bit ambigious. I tried doing

{% if user.is_admin or (something.enable_thing and user.can_do_thething) %}

But you arent allowed Parentheses. The docs say to use nested ifs (or elifs in this case, i guess, as its an OR) , but I dont want to repeat the same HTML inside 2 if blocks, which sounds horrible.

Comment: leave it without paranthesis. I think it works ;)

Comment: You don't want to use nested if's and also parenthesis are invalid in `if` block, hence clearly framework does not support what you are asking for get over with it and move your complex logic to template tags or views.

Answer (score 19):

As Mihai Zamfir commented it should work as expected. As Django documentation mentions:

Use of both **and** and **or** clauses within the same tag is allowed, with **and** having **higher** precedence than **or** e.g.:

`{% if athlete_list and coach_list or cheerleader_list %}`

will be interpreted like:

`if (athlete_list and coach_list) or cheerleader_list`

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/#boolean-operators

Comment: Could you provide a link to the official documentation as well? Helpful answer

Comment: And inverted: `{% if athlete_list and coach_list or athlete_list and cheerleader_list %}` would equal `if athlete_list and (coach_list or cheerleader_list)`

Answer (score 10):

you could do the check in your view and pass a flag to the context.

```
show_html = user.is_admin or (something.enable_thing and user.can_do_the_thing)
context['show_html'] = show_html
```

Then in your template you could check the flag

`{% if show_html %}`

Comment: I wouldn't put this logic into a view but rather use a custom tag

Comment: What if one of those variables need to be a loop iteration variable? django disappointed me about this.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the case like you said: `A or (B and C)`, then Sven's answer would work appropriately because the `and` would automatically have higher precedence according to the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/templates/builtins/#boolean-operators).

However, if you wish to do something like  `(A or B) and C`, then you could instead create and use [custom template filters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/howto/custom-template-tags/).

**NOTE**: Filters can only take *at most* two arguments, so they will only be useful if say, for example, you are comparing multiple attributes from 1 or 2 objects.